# Signature algorithm/protocol with fillable gaps?

Tags: signature, protocol-design

Consider how a [cheque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheque)-book works: Alice goes to the Bank, and gets some incomplete messages, like `Alice would like the Bank to give _____ (or the bearer of this paper) the following: _____`. This message is verifiably from the Bank, because it's written on a special paper, however the message is incomplete.

In order to transmit the message, Alice needs to fill it out: the message is not considered valid unless there is content in the gaps. Once Alice fills it out, the cheque is considered as if it's signed by the bank (excluding cases where [Alice does not have the money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dishonoured_cheque)). The contents of the gaps cannot be modified afterwards without making it obvious that it's been tampered with; this is physically accomplished by adding marks that cannot be written over, like `x$100.00x`, or using [special banker's numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_numerals#Standard_numbers).

There are also other ways of modifying the way the cheque's validity is verified: for example, if the cheque is [crossed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_of_cheques), then some values for the recipient field become invalid; if Alice crosses out the "or bearer" part, then a cheque saying `Alice would like the Bank to give _the bearer of this paper_ (̶o̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶b̶e̶a̶r̶e̶r̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶p̶a̶p̶e̶r̶)̶ the following: _x$100.00x_` becomes invalid because of the crossing. Finally, some values of the gaps are semantically invalid, and a cheque containing these will also not be considered correct: `Alice would like the Bank to give _Charlie_ the following: _a pony_` is not a request that the bank will fulfill.

I'm looking for some algorithm or protocol that would allow Bob (the Bank) to give Alice some incomplete message, and then Alice can finalize this message by filling in the gaps (importantly, this needs to be done offline, without talking to Bob), and then Charlie can see this message and trust it as if Bob signed it. Preferably it would also allow a way to fail this signature verification if the message fails semantic checks, but that could also be on an upper layer.

So far I've managed to come up with the following:

- Bob gives Alice an ephemeral keypair S, and a message like:
  `Alice would like the Bank to give {{rcpt}} the following: {{amount}} pennies. Constraints: {{rcpt}} must be an account ID; {{amount}} must be an integer no larger than 1000000; the completion message must be signed by public key S.public`. This message is signed by Bob, but is considered invalid until:
- Alice creates a message like `rcpt=Charlie; amount=10000`, signs it with S.private, then concatenates it with Bob's message, thus providing the values for the gaps.
- Alice can now give this message to Charlie, and Charlie can check the validity of the original Bob message, the signature of the appended part, and the semantic constraints on the appended part. If all succeed, then the message is as good as signed by Bob.

Is there a more standard way to do this?

Comment: What prevent the Alice to sign all together at once? Why do we need the gaps? Bob sends the template and Alice fills and signs. What is the problem here?

Comment: @kelalaka Perhaps the example of a cheque makes it a bit confusing. What I want is for Bob to give Alice a sort of limited permission to sign a message on his behalf, without needing to communicate with Bob. Another reason for this is if Bob is going on vacation and wants Alice to write his emails for him; then Bob would give her incomplete messages like `Bob is away, but Alice says this on his behalf: _____`, and recipients would trust those messages as much as they trust Bob's own.

Comment: What will prevent Alice to write 9999 instead of 1000?

Comment: @kelalaka As in, there's space for 4 bytes but we want it to not exceed some limit? I'm thinking that it could be embedded in some high-level document format, whose specifications require the value to be limited in some way for the document to be considered well-formed. [XML facets](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/schema_facets.asp) do this, for example.